# Trigonometric inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Solve inequality per x:
$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\sin(2x)>1$$

I need some start, I tried to factor but i can't get something easier to solve, for example:
$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)>1-\sin(2x)$$
$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)>\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)>(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2$$
What now?

Comment: You have a mistake on the last line; that should be $(\sin(x)-\cos(x))^2$, not $(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a trick: set $x=\frac{\pi}{4}-y$

This reduces the inequality to

> $2\cos^2y+\sqrt{2}\cos y-2>0$

Answer (score 2):

If we set $\displaystyle u=\sin x+\cos x,u^2=1+\sin2x\le2 \implies -\sqrt2\le u\le\sqrt2$

$$\sin x+\cos x+\sin2x>1\iff u+u^2-1>1\iff (u+2)(u-1)>0$$

as $u+2>0,$ we need $\displaystyle u-1>0$

$\displaystyle\implies \sin x+\cos x>1$

$\iff \sin x>1-\cos x$

$\displaystyle\iff2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2>2\sin^2\dfrac x2 $

$\displaystyle\iff\frac{2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2}{2\sin^2\dfrac x2}>1
$
$\displaystyle\iff\cot\dfrac x2>1 $

$\displaystyle\iff n\pi\le\dfrac x2<n\pi+\frac\pi4$ where $n$ is any integer